# How can I create a SVG chart offline with highcharts for python?

Tags: python, highcharts

I'm trying to create an SVG chart with highcharts in Python for a windows application. I was able to download thanks to Server Side export, but I would need to export it offline. I saw that there is also a Client-side export but I couldn't get it to work outside Jupyter.

How can I do? Is there a method like `download` for client-side exporting? Or are there alternatives other than highcharts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*FULL DISCLOSURE: I'm the primary author of Highcharts for Python.*

- **Helpful Tutorial:** https://core-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/tutorials/exporting.html#client-side-exporting
- **Documentation on the `Exporting` Class:** https://core-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/api/options/exporting/index.html#highcharts_core.options.exporting.Exporting

Client-side exporting is configured through the `exporting` options via the `.options.exporting.Exporting` class. Here's a snippet of content from [one of the tutorials in the documentation](https://core-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/tutorials/exporting.html#client-side-exporting):

> Using Highcharts for Python, you can configure client-side export
> within the `Chart.options` settings by configuring the `options.exporting`
> property.
>
> In particular, you can apply configuration through an `Exporting`
> instance, which lets you configure how your chart will support
> exporting from within the user’s browser when the chart is rendered.
> Here’s a quick example, assuming you have a `Chart`
> instance called `my_chart`:
>
> ```
> exporting_options = Exporting(enabled = True,
>                               filename = 'your-exported-chart',
>                               show_table = True,
>                               table_caption = "Your Chart's Caption Goes Here",
>                               accessibility = {
>                                   'enabled': True
>                               })
>
> exporting_options.buttons['contextButton'].menu_items = ['printChart',
> 'separator', 'downloadPNG']
>
> my_chart.options.exporting = exporting_options
> ```
>
> And that’s it. With the code above you’ve now configured some basic
> logic that:
>
> - Enables client-side export of the my_chart visualization.
> - Gives an exported chart image a default filename of
>   `'your-exported-chart'` (not including the file’s extension).
> - Makes sure that the exported or printed version of your chart includes
>   the chart’s underlying data table (thanks to the `show_table` property
>   being set to True), and
> - Gives users the ability to either print the chart or download a PNG
>   version of the chart, but nothing else (by setting the relevant
>   buttons shown in the context menu).
>
> Highcharts Core supports client-side export to a number of formats,
> including:
>
> - PNG
> - JPEG
> - SVG
> - CSV
> - Excel
>
> And you can also configure the client-side export to fall back to
> server-side export should it fail.

Hope this helps!